# Get queue size of ThreadPoolTaskExecutor and add to queue in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have the following class which has multiple custom `ThreadPoolTaskExecutors` I am showing it with one in this example.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class ExecutorConfig {
    @Bean(name = "streetCheckerExecutor")
    public Executor getStreetAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(50);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(1000000);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("streetCheckerExecutor-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

I have the following class which gets content from the database, I want to be able to check the queue size of `streetCheckerExecutor` and if it's less than a certain number, to add the content to the queue

```
@Component
public class StreetChecker {

    @Autowired
    StreetRepository streetRepository;

    @Autowired
    StreetCheckService streetChecker;

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void checkStreets() {
        try {
            List<Street> streetList = streetRepository.getStreets();

            for (int i = 0; i < streetList.size(); i++) {
                streetChecker.run(streetList.get(i));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("---------------------");
        }
    }

}
```

And below is the worker class

```
@Component
public class StreetCheckService {
    @Async("streetCheckerExecutor")
    public void run(Content content) {    
        try {
            //do work
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

        }
    }
}
```

I am working with a lot of data and I don't want to grab everything from the database every time, but I want to check the queue size of `streetCheckerExecutor` and if it's less than a number, I want to get more content from the database and add it to the `streetCheckerExecutor` queque

Below is how I'm thinking I can do it by converting the above `checkStreets` to the one below

```
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void checkStreets() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            // check the queue size of streetCheckerExecutor
            // if less than a number
            // add to the queue
            // else keep waiting and will try again in X minutes
        } catch (Exception e) {

        } finally {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000 * 60);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But how would I be able to get the size of the queue in the `checkStreets()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just autowire in your `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` and get the queue with `getThreadPoolExecutor().getQueue()`.

```
@Autowire
@Qualifier("streetCheckerExecutor")
private Executor streetExecutor;

@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void checkStreets() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            final BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = streetExecutor.getThreadPoolExecutor().getQueue();
            if(queue.size() <= 5) {
                queue.add(() -> {
                     final List<Street> streetList = streetRepository.getStreets();
                     streetList.forEach(street -> {
                         streetChecker.run(street);
                     });
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        } finally {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000 * 60);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i'm not sure this is what you meant, but something like this maybe.

Comment: I just started implementing this and testing it, and I'm getting `Field streetCheckerExecutor in com.mycompany.StreetCheck required a bean of type 'com.mycompany.configuration.ExecutorConfig' that could not be found.` Even though I have the `@Bean(name = "streetCheckerExecutor")` annotation above the `getStreetAsyncExecutor()` method

Comment: it looks like your application can't find your `@Configuration` annotated class `ExecutorConfig`.

What does your main class look like with `@SpringBootApplication` annotation. And how does your folder structure look like. Spring boot per default scans all packages below the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class to find configuration annotated classes.

Comment: unless you have any custom `@ComponentScan` annotations that overrides the default behaviour.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I did  `@Autowired
 @Qualifier("streetCheckerExecutor")
 private java.util.concurrent.Executor streetCheckerExecutor;`
I used `Executor` as the class